# Change hostname with a variable with for loop

Tags: linux, scripting, variable

I am trying to change the "**hostname --transient**" to some computers with a for loop using a variable. I want it to collect the "**hostname -f**" from the server itself and, using the variable, change it automatically. When I run it, it tells me "**Invalid number of arguments.**"

**Command:**

```bash
for i in `cat /tmp/serverlist`; do
    echo "Hostname in $i"
    ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@$i "hostname=$(hostname -f); hostnamectl --transient set-hostname $hostname"
done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are using double quotes, the `$hostname` variable is being expanded on your local machine, before launching `ssh`, so it s presumably empty. You can get the same error with:

```bash
$ hostnamectl --transient set-hostname 
Too few arguments.
```

Since you want these to be expanded on the remote host, use single quotes instead (also fixing a couple of other bad practices):

```bash
while IFS= read -r i; do
   ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no "root@$i" 'hostnamectl --transient set-hostname "$(hostname -f)"'
done
```

Comment: It was because of that, thank you very much! Tips for improvement are appreciated!